# How do I get the value of a textarea in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to get Textarea value in jquery, if I am using

```
<form name="myform"> 
<textarea name="msg" id="msg"></textarea>
</form>
```

This syntax is not working properly

```
 var text = $('textarea#message').val();
```

can anybody tell me about the things ?

Comment: What is the value of the ID attribute on your textarea HTML tag?

Comment: You shouldn't be using $('tag#id') as it calls the selection engine twice. You should just use $('#id') as there should only be a single element with that id.

Comment: @Mervyn - from the page in the jQuery documentation that mentions that:  "As always, remember that as a developer, your time is typically the most valuable resource. Do not focus on optimization of selector speed unless it is clear that performance needs to be improved."

Comment: Also, at some point jQuery have switched to using the querySelectorAll() method that is exposed as part of the JavaScript Web API.  While the internals of this method are not publicly available (and are not jQuery-specific), the jQuery engine does not chain calls to the selection engine any longer.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy - I can understand that for when you get long complex selectors involving has, not, and other filters. For something as simple as this, it is definitely worth noting and doing.

Comment: @Mervyn - sure, I'm just pointing out that, for someone who doesn't even understand what a selector *is*, introducing shortcuts will just confuse them even further.

Comment: @Mervyn - "it calls the selector engine twice"...that's not accurate at all.  I advocate the user of only `#id` *if* it fits the page, 99% of the time it does, but that's not *always* true.  When an ID is as generic as this I won't remove it from the OPs code, as my answer shows.  What if you had `$("#msg").click(...)`, and if it was `<textarea id="msg">` you wanted this, but on *another* page (same included script), it had `<div id="msg">`? There *are* valid cases to keep the tag, this isn't absolute.

Answer (score 8):

Your idea is right, but your selector is a bit off:

```
$('textarea#msg').val(); //not "message"
```

The ID of the [ID-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) needs to match exactly :)

Answer (score 4):

`$("#msg").val();`

Comment: actually this is the best answer!

Comment: @adardesign: and why is that?

Comment: Because the selector is a id, So it maps to the native `getElementById()`, in other words, the selector is the fastest. see http://tinyurl.com/2ctdw8c out of many jQuery's best performance articles

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
$("textarea#msg").val(result.message);
```

or

```
$("textarea#msg").val()
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be targeting the text area incorrectly.  Try `var text = $('textarea#msg').val()`.

Answer (score 0):

If your textarea's Id is "msg" then your selector needs to use that.

```
var text = $('textarea#msg').val();
```

Comment: Would the anonymous downvoter care to comment?  (Pretty sure this was a retribution downvote for a negative comment I made on someone else's answer, even though I did *not* downvote them...)

Answer (score 0):

your code :

```
<form name="myform"> 
<textarea name="msg" id="msg"></textarea>
</form>
```

Your id name is : msg, not message
so your code should be like this :

```
var text = $('textarea#msg').val();
```