# Retrieve textarea value within a div element in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I have a few div elements where within each div tag, I have other form elements. For eg:

```
<div id="div1"><input type="text" name="answer" id="answer"></div>
<div id="div2"><textarea name="answer" id="answer">Some Value</textarea></div>
<div id="div3"><textarea name="answer" id="answer">Some Value</textarea></div>
```

How can I retrieve the textarea for div3 only. Here is what I have, but I am always only getting back the text area of div2

```
var divElement = dojo.byId('div3');
if ($('textarea', divElement).length > 0){
    var text = $('textarea#answer').val();
}
```

Help!

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: Why are you mixing Dojo and jQuery like that? E.g. you could just write `var text = $('#div3 textarea').val()`.

Comment: As an aside, your element IDs must be unique - you can't call everything `answer`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of a textarea in jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119709/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-textarea-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

```
var firstTextarea = $('#div3').find('textarea :first').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following selector

```
var value = $('#div3 textarea').val();
alert(value);
```

Note: Your solution is using duplicate `id` values for the textarea and input tags.  It's not legal to have multiple id`s and will lead you to pain down the road.  It would be best to change your tags to have unique id's and then query that directly.  For example

HTML:

```
<div id="div1"><input type="text" name="answer" id="answer1"></div>
<div id="div2"><textarea name="answer" id="answer2">Some Value</textarea></div>
<div id="div3"><textarea name="answer" id="answer3">Some Value</textarea></div>
```

Javascript

```
var value = $('#answer3').val();
alert(value);
```

Comment: Thanks - Will keep this mind. Unfortulately, I have these div being generated dynamically and only 1 div is visible at any point in time.

Answer (score 0):

well, you have assigned same ids to 3 elements, that is not a good practice. Every element should have unique id. In case you have assigned same id, you will always retrieve first element from your code.
If you want to retrieve div 3 textarea, use following selector :

```
$('#div3 textarea).val()
```